# Replacing ceramic capacitors with film in PSU

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, amplifier, ceramic

Some Behringer Truth B2031 came back from a friend and they're acting up. first thing I noticed was the four .1uf ceramics that are in parrellel with the bridge rectifier diodes have experienced violent explosions, likely due to electrical storm. The highest voltage I can find for these locally is 50V, and the original ones were about twice the size physically so I'm assuming there were rated for higher voltages.

Even at Mouser, .1uf is the highest ceramics go and the selection is minimal with to +50V ones being expensive (I need 8 of them).

So, seeing as there are plenty of .1uf films rated for +500V for a fraction of the cost, can I use them instead?

[image: B2031 (rev. G) PSU]

Comment: Let me ask a question: If manufacturers could do the job with much cheaper film caps than ceramics, don't you think they"d use them instead? Furthermore, I suggest you go back to Digikey and rerun you search, but do it right this time. For instance, I see a 1 uF, 500V ceramic for 56 cents.

Comment: Well I'm no pro for sure, but in my limited experience, poly*** film caps are usually the most expensive and sought after (for audio). The 50V ceramics I got from the store were a few cents each, the originals looked exactly the same but probably 100V (behringer are well know for using the cheapest part they can get away with). Conversely the .1uf Wima film caps I have lying around were closer to $0.80 and rated 160VAC 250VDC. I don't need anything else from Digikey so postage would kill me but thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Ok actually I only searched for ceramic disc. Are you saying that MLCC is fine in parallel with rectifier diodes? I heard they can cause oscillations which I think is why these caps are there.

Comment: Is this the part of the circuit you're talking about? The schematic does not show any 0.1µF capacitors in parallel with the diodes. (There are other revisions, but the only differencees are in the values of R3/R4.)

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast could you perhaps give a reason rather than just turning it round on the questioner? I'm guessing that the missing piece of information might be a requirement for "X" rating: http://www.kemet.com/Lists/Filestore/EvoxRifaRFIandSMD.pdf

Comment: What CL said ... The capacitors in your schematic look like electrolytics to me. What are the maximum voltages for Vcc+ and Vcc-?

Comment: Now that you've added a schematic, it is clear that the other commenters are correct. The 10 uF caps are electrolytic. And, for what it's worth, C15 and C18 can be 25 or 35 volt units. I assume the designers used 50 volt units just to simplify the parts list. The 150 ohm resistors guarantee that there are no noticeable input surge/spike requirements. However, your original comment that all four caps violently exploded suggests that the caps are the least of your worries. A major over-voltage event has occurred, and you probably have a whole string of dead components downstream.

Comment: Yes that is the part of the circuit, though I didn't include a schematic because I couldn't find a revision that included the caps that are definitely present on this PCB (its labelled RevI or maybe Rev1). In any case, I don't think they were doing much anyway, i just replaced them with 50V versions. The real issue I think is that whatever blew those caps must have blown the LM3886 that drives the woofer. Some new ones are on the way.